# How do I create a delay in js akin to sleep()

Tags: javascript, timeout, delay, delayed-execution, timedelay

I need to create a delay in js. I could use setTimeout but then the code continues to execute. During the delay, I want the script to do nothing. Is there any way to do this??
To be more clear:
Eg. If I am doing two animations.

1)first animation.
2)delay(nothing is done for a second)
3)second animation.

EDIT:

First Animation:

```
  function animateScreen() {
  var audio = new Audio("http://www.sounds.beachware.com/2illionzayp3may/illwavul/CLNKBEEP.mp3");
  $("body").toggleClass("wrongSeries");
  audio.play();
}

function wrongChoice() {

  animateScreen();
  setTimeout(animateScreen, 100);

}
```

2) delay

3) Second Animation:

```
animateYellow(true);
      setTimeout(function() {
        animateYellow(false);
      }, 500);



function animateYellow(lightup) {

  if (lightup) {
    var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3");
    audio.play();
  }
  $("#4").toggleClass("animateYellow");

}
```

This is the code I am currently using. The second animation exists for four different colors.

Comment: Put your code in distinct blocks that can be called independently and use timers.  You shouldn't block your code from execution.

Comment: by timers, do you mean setTimer and clearTimer?? Currently my code for the animations are in different blocks but they are being called via setTimeout one after another. Even if I do the same with timer, wouldn't the result be same ??

Comment: I do mean by using `setTimeout()`, yes.  If you post some code I can show you what I mean.  Just post a couple of functions that run animations and I'll give you an example.

Comment: Ive edited the question to include some code. Not sure if this example is understandable. Tell me if Im not clear.

Comment: Are the animations css transitions?  Also, do you care about when the audio stops playing, or is that not relevant to the animation flow?

Comment: Yes the animations are simple background changes(change color and then back to original color again). Would like the audio to play for a duration between these changes.

Comment: Are you using, or can you use, jQuery?  If so you can do all that you need with event handling, rather than timouts

Comment: The second animation is activated through a click event .  Full Code Here: http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/JKoYqR